# Error with KNPpaginator and Join Query with Symfony3

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, symfony, knppaginator

Iam developing a web application for a schoolwork in symfony 3, i need to show a table and i need that this table shows only 5 results and also sort the columns with the knppaginator.
im using the following code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder(); 
    $dql = $em
    ->select( 'w.id, c.nombre AS Cliente, u.nombre AS  Usuario, w.titulo AS Titulo, w.descripcion AS Descripcion, w.fecharegistro AS FechaRegistro, w.fechainicio AS FechaInicio, w.fechaentrega AS FechaEntrega, w.prioridad AS prioridad, w.terminado AS terminado')
    ->add('from','ClientBundle:Client c')
    ->innerJoin('WorkBundle:Work', 'w', 'WITH', 'c.id=w.iDCliente')
    ->innerJoin('UserBundle:User', 'u', 'WITH', 'w.iDUsuario=u.id')
    ->where('w.terminado=0 and u.nombre= :name')->setParameter('name',$session->get('name'))
    ->getQuery();
    $works = $dql->getResult();


 $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

        $pagination = $paginator->paginate($works, $request->query->getInt('page',1),5);

    return $this->render("UserBundle:User:main.html.twig",array("vacio"=>$works,"fechaActual"=>$fechaActual,"name"=>$session->get("name"),"pagination"=>$pagination));
```

if i dont use the "getResult()", the paginator gets the query directly, so knppaginator can sort the columns but cant paginate them, but if i use the "getResult()" method the table is correctly paginated but the table cant be sorted

Comment: Could you clarify your question please?

Comment: English is not my native language so its hard for me but ill try...

Comment: you receive any error when you pass directly the query?

Comment: nope, there arent any error, just knppaginator dont work in the way of sort the tables or dont paginate the table but sort works